# AES key string throws exceptions

Tags: java, cryptography

I am trying to write a class that will encrypt/decrypt text using AES.

I want to generate a key, store the key in a database column and use that key to encrypt/decrypt corresponding text in the database row containing the key.

The following is the class that I wrote to generate the key and do encryption and decryption tasks.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class StringDecryptor {

    public static String encrypt(String text, String key) {
        Key aesKey = null;
        Cipher cipher = null;
        byte[] encrypted = null;
        try {
            aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
            encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StringDecryptor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StringDecryptor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StringDecryptor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StringDecryptor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StringDecryptor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StringDecryptor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return new String(encrypted);
    }

    public static String decrypt(String text, String key) {
        Key aesKey = null;
        Cipher cipher;
        String decrypted = null;
        try {
            aesKey  = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
            decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes()));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StringDecryptor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StringDecryptor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StringDecryptor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StringDecryptor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StringDecryptor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StringDecryptor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return decrypted;
    }

    public static String generateKey() {
        SecretKey secretKey = null;
        try {
            secretKey = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StringDecryptor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        String keyString = bytesToString(secretKey.getEncoded());
        return keyString;
    }

    public static String bytesToString(byte[] b) {
        String decoded = null;
        try {
            decoded = new String(b, "UTF-8");            
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StringDecryptor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return decoded;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String key = generateKey();
        System.out.println("key: " + key);
        String str = "This is the original string...";
        String enc = encrypt(str, key);
        System.out.println("enc: " + enc);
        String dec = decrypt(enc, key);
        System.out.println("dec: " + dec);
    }
}
```

This code is throwing the following exception.

```
SEVERE: null
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 26 bytes
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineGetKeySize(AESCipher.java:372)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.passCryptoPermCheck(Cipher.java:1052)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1010)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:786)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:849)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1213)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1153)
    at com.innolabmm.software.luckydraw.utils.StringDecryptor.encrypt(StringDecryptor.java:27)
    at com.innolabmm.software.luckydraw.utils.StringDecryptor.main(StringDecryptor.java:95)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:556)
    at com.innolabmm.software.luckydraw.utils.StringDecryptor.encrypt(StringDecryptor.java:42)
    at com.innolabmm.software.luckydraw.utils.StringDecryptor.main(StringDecryptor.java:95)
Java Result: 1
```

Is there any way to generate a key string that does not cause the AES key conversion to throw exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to encrypt with the AES-algorithm you will need to base your key on an atleast 128bit String. (Other values are also legal, but I don't have them in my head)

To convert that into number of characters needed in your provided key-string you can take 128 divided by 8

```
128 / 8 = 16 alpha-numeric characters
```

This should solve your problem.

**EDIT:**

Answer on comment about BASE64:
BASE64 is a different way of encoding a string. The result of a BASE64-encoding may be a 128bit string, but not by default. There is not actually a default length of the outcome of a BASE64-encoding. The result may be 8 characters or 512, or some other output that conforms with the encoding rules of BASE64, it all depends on the string you are encoding.

Comment: Is Base64 a 128bit string?

Answer (score 0):

AES needs a key that is of length either 128, 192, or 256 bits. Try using a longer key.

Comment: I guess the key was the right length when it was generated but became shorter when encryption happened.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example to generate AES key:

```
private static SecretKeySpec key;
private static final int ENCRYPTION_KEY_SIZE = 128;

private static SecretKey generateKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

KeyGenerator keyGenerator = null;
keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keyGenerator.init(ENCRYPTION_KEY_SIZE);

SecretKey key = keyGenerator.generateKey();
return key;
}

public void createNewEncrytionKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, Exception {
SecretKey newKey = generateKey();
saveKey(newKey);
LogUtil.logMessage("createNewEncrytionKey", "New random encryption key was created.", logger);
key = (SecretKeySpec) newKey;
}
```

you can then use that key to encrypt\decrypt your code (in the example I convert the encrypted value to hexdecimal format:

```
/**
     * Encrypt a given text
     * 
     * @param value String to encrypt
     * @return encrypted String value
     */
    public static String encrypt(String value) {

    if (null == key) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Secret encryption key not found!");
    }

    Cipher c;
    String result = null;
    try {
        c = Cipher.getInstance(ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        // 1. convert value to byte array
        byte[] bvalue = value.getBytes();
        // 2. convert to encrypted byte array
        byte[] encrypted = c.doFinal(bvalue);
        // 3. convert to hexadecimal representation
        result = toHexString(encrypted);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LogUtil.logError("encrypt", e, logger);
    }

    return result;
    }


/**
     * Decrypt a given text
     * 
     * @param value encrypted String value
     * @return Decrypted value
     */
    public static String decrypt(String value) {

    if (null == key) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Secret encryption key not found!");
    }

    Cipher c;
    String result = null;
    try {
        // 1. convert hex to encrypted byte array
        byte[] encrypted = hexToByteArray(value);
        // 2. convert to decrypted byte array
        c = Cipher.getInstance(ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decrypted = c.doFinal(encrypted);
        // 3. convert to plain string
        result = bytesToString(decrypted);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LogUtil.logError("decrypt", e, logger);
    }

    return result;
    }
```

Comment: The problem isn't about encrypting/decrypting. It's about generating a key and storing that key somewhere so that I can use it for future encryption and decryption tasks later.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with AES or cryptography. You are however trying to interpret a random sequence of bytes as UTF-8 encoded characters (`b` being the AES key):

`String decoded = new String(b, "UTF-8");`

That is not going to work, since your byte array will most likely contain several byte sequences, which are invalid for UTF-8. If you need a string representation of the byte array content, you have to encode the data using e.g. base64 or hex encoding.